# Get average value of a range of cells where another cell's value is greater than or equal to 80

Tags: excel

[image: My spreadsheet]

Does anyone know how to find average temperature, but only for the days where humidity was greater than or equal to 80?

Thanks!

Comment: Research the `AVERAGEIF` function

Answer (score 3):

Use `AVERAGEIF()`:

```
=AVERAGEIF(D2:D10, ">80", B2:B10)
```

This answer assumes that:

- The `Temperature` column is column `B`
- The `Humidity` column is column `D`
- You only have data in rows 2 through 10

You can adjust this formula to fit your actual worksheet.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(D:D,">=80",B:B)
```

where `D` is `Humidity` column and `B` is `Temperature` column.